# Creating a custom view when a tableview cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

How would I create a new view that displays unique information for the selection of a specific tableview cell? For example, if row 1  is selected then the new image will have unique information to that cell which would be different from the view if row 2 was selected.

Here is the code for my tableview.

```
import UIKit

struct Data {
var sectionTitle = String()
var rowTitles = [String]()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var dataArray = [Data(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]),
    Data(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["row 1"]),
    Data(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2"])
]
var searchArray = [Data]()
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchArray[section].rowTitles.count
    } else {
        return dataArray[section].rowTitles.count
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
    cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
    if searching {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell!
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchArray.count
    } else {
        return dataArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return dataArray[section].sectionTitle
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let index = indexPath.row
    let data = dataArray[index]
    let destVC = SecondViewController(data: data)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}

}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        searching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        searching = true
        searchArray =   dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased()) || $0.rowTitles.map{$0.lowercased()}.contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Here is my second view controller which shows my generic stack view that I would like to change to display different images and labels depending on the cell that is selected in the tableview.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var data: Data!
var dataView: DataView { return self.view as! DataView}

init(data: Data) {
    self.data = data
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func loadView() {
    self.view = DataView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}

}


class DataView: UIView {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    setupViews()
    setupConstraints()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews() {
    self.addSubview(stack)
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stack.spacing = 10
}

func setupConstraints() {
    stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    dataImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    dataImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    dataImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
}

let dataNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.text = "Organization"
    return label
} ()

let dataDescriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 8
    label.text = "Description"
    return label
} ()

let dataImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.backgroundColor = .gray
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 260).isActive = true
    return imageView
} ()

let visitButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Visit", for: .normal)
    return button
} ()

lazy var stack: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [dataImage, dataNameLabel, dataDescriptionLabel, visitButton])
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.axis = .vertical
    return stack
} ()

}
```

The objective is to have a user select a tableview cell, and for the stack view to display specific information that corresponds to that cell. How would I create this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to pass information to a new view controller when an item in your TableViewController has been selected.

But I'm interpreting your question, as you know how to pass information, but you want to pass different information, maybe an image to your second view controller, based on which TableViewCell was selected.

The way that I would do this, is to have an array with images in your SecondViewController. When an item is selected in your TableViewController, also pass the indexPath.row to the SecondViewController. From there, you can load the image from your imagesArray at the indexPath.row that you have passed to it. You can do this by having an integer value in your SecondViewController, that is populated right before you segue.